# Specific station not showing up on airmon-ng though there are two devices connected

Tags: network

[image]

I'm on a mac using kali linux.

Why aren't any specific devices showing up despite two devices currently using the wifi?

Comment: Are those devices connected on 5GHz band?

Comment: Is it in monitor mode (`airmon-ng start [device name]`)

Comment: Yes, it’s in monitor mode. Not sure if it’s in 5ghz band, does it have to?

Comment: If the network also exists on 5GHz and the devices are using that, and you are only listening on 2.4GHz, then of course you won't be able to see them.